# Add a user trusted certificate to FireTV

Tags: certificate, amazon-fire-tv

Is there a way to add a CA certificate to a FireTV stick device?

I'm able to log in to the device using adb, have entered development menu, but cannot find anything.

What I need is to add a self-signed certificate to the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. The gist:

```
adb push charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem /storage/emulated/0/Download
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem" -t "application/x-x509-ca-cert"
```

From https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/network-proxy.html

And I just replaced `charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem` above with my own certificate file; `mycert.cer` - yes, even the cer format works.

Answer (score 3):

I have just followed this instruction plus other instrctions to install my Home RootCA Certificate as Trusted on my Fire TV, I needed it in order to connect to my NAS via HTTPS and verify it's certificate (my NAS have a HTTPS Certificate issued by my Home RootCA)

This are all the steps I have done and they worked like a charm:

1. Download and extract adb from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows.zip
2. For ease of use add the extracted folder to your PATH (This ca be skipped but you will need to run adb from inside the folder)
3. Open cmd and move to the folder containing your certificate (If you do not use PATH for adb I suggest you have both adb and your certificate in the same folder and move cmd there)
4. Enable debug on Fire TV (https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/connecting-adb-to-device.html#turnondebugging)
5. Connect to your Fire TV via "adb connect" (https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/connecting-adb-to-device.html#connectingadboptions)
6. Push your certificate with "adb push"
7. Install your certificate with "adb shell"
8. Provide a name for your certificate and make sure "VPN and apps" is choosen for certification usage
9. You will need to insert your Amazon password for security reason.
10. Enjoy your new certificate

Example commands below:

```
adb connect 1.1.1.1:5555
adb push MyRootCA.crt /storage/emulated/0/Download
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MyRootCA.crt" -t "application/x-x509-ca-cert"
```

Hope this could help someone :)